# Is the below statement on satisfiability true.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

> A logical formula is unsatisfiable **if and only if** for the formula to be true, at least one of its variables must be both true and false.

I discovered SAT today, and wanted to try my hands at solving it. I arrived at the above statement as a general principle for any attempt I want to make at solving SAT. Is the principle true?

Comment: can a value be both true and false ? if not then any statement that leads a variable to a value of both true and false can't be satisfied because true and false aren't both satisfied at the same time.

Comment: "at least *be* of its variable". You mean *one* ?

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Comment: @Roddy Macphee is that an "if and only if" though? I think it is, but want to confirm.

Comment: my point was unless true and false can be satisfied at the same time, your statement can only be satisfied by true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it has at least one variable (I say this, because $\bot$ is unsatisfiable and, if you are working with clauses, the clause $\{ \}$ is unsatisfiable, but neither has at least one variable), then yes, that's correct, because the right hand side basically says:

'If formula $F$ is true, then some variable $P$ is both true and false'

... which is to say: the truth of the formula $F$ leads to a contradiction,

...which means that $F$ cannot be true, which means that $F$ is unsatisfiable

So: your right hand side implies the left hand side.

And of course the left hand side implies the right hand side, since if $F$ is unsatisfiable, then $F$ is a contradiction, and so $F$ implies everything, including that one of its variables (again, assuming it has a variable) is both true and false.

Comment: What is $\bot$?

Comment: @TobiAlafin It is a symbol used in logic to denote a contradiction. IN some logic systems it is part of the language to express statements, and $\bot$ is a statement that is always false.